# Search special items (movies) in google api

Tags: api, search, google-api, google-search, google-search-api

hi i have a project and need to search movies name in any language .
in google i can find them but i need some api for project .like JSON api of list of movies and tv show with original name and rate or something

like this result search but in json:
https://www.google.com/search?q=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF+%D8%A2%D9%87%D9%86%DB%8C+2010

i found this:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction
and this filters
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

but it's show website results not special item !

and i found imdb api:
https://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/i/ironman.json
that was working fine but only search with english name

so any help?!!